# How to convert each field in a column in a dataframe to its own json?

Tags: python, json

These all produce different values but what I'm trying to get is to convert the second column into a json where each row is different - i dont want x y z on each row, i want a json with x on row 1, json with y on row 2 etc

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'First_Column_Name':  ['A', 'B','C'],
        'Second_Column_Name': ['X', 'Y','Z']
        }
        
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First_Column_Name','Second_Column_Name'])
print (df)

df_new = df.assign(Second_Column_Name = lambda x: x.to_json())
print(df_new)

df['Second_Column_Name'] = pd.Series([df['Second_Column_Name']]).to_json()
print(df)

for i in df.index:
    df['Second_Column_Name'] = pd.Series([df.iloc[i]['Second_Column_Name']]).to_json()
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: In column 1 i want to leave it as it is, in column 2 i want a json where it is 0:x on row 1, 1:Y on row 2 and 2:Z on row 3. Right now it is putting the whole column on each row, but i just want the value for each row to remain on each row but change the format from string to json

Comment: Are you looking for something like `df['Second_Column_Name'] = [{k:v} for k,v in df['Second_Column_Name'].to_dict().items()]`  ?